# Kubernetes. Is it possible one release in two namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, tarantool

We have [tarantool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantool) in the Kubernetes cluster. One of tarantool's part has big in size. We need to be able to manage this separately from the main release.
Our idea is to divide by two namespaces. Is it possible? What problems will we have?
Are there other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: It is not clear from your question.
Are you looking to have multiple environments for same tarantool-based appliction in same cluster? Then it is OK for me to have separate namespace for each environment.
OR
In case if you are looking to split big tarantool instance into multiple? Then you have to implement horizontal scaling for your application. For example utilize vshard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:** Our idea is to divide by two namespaces. Is it possible?

> No, because [Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) are a logical partitioning capability that enable one Kubernetes cluster to be used by multiple users.

**2:** Are there other ways to solve the problem?

> Yes

- [Fine Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/)
- [Running Multiple Instances of Your App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/scale/scale-intro/)